# Python install package version based on another package version

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, python-packaging, conflicting-libraries

How can I do something like the following in my `requirements.in`?

```
package_1; package_2==specific_version
```

What I would like to install is the version of `package_1` that requires as dependency a particular version of `package_2`.

Comment: Couldn't you just leave out the first package and let `pip` do the rest?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: @sinoroc 
in my requirements.in I have n packages
many packages have as dependency different versions of the same package; let's say package_1 has as dependency numpy==7.9.8 (it is just an example I do not know if this version really exists) and package_2 has as dependency numpy==6.5.4. There's a conflict.

I would like to say: Hey requirements.in find the version of package_1 that has numpy==6.5.4 as dependency

Comment: That is the job of the dependency resolver embedded in the installer (pip?), it has an algorithm dedicated to solving this kind of problems. If you simply list `package_1` and `package_2`, the installer will first attempt a dependency resolution that satisfies all constraints.